# Can I use pt-online-schema-change to change a primary key?

Tags: mysql, percona, pt-online-schema-change

I'm considering using `pt-online-schema-change` to `ALTER` a primary key (changing it from one column, to a composite primary index) of a table. Are there any limitations to doing this? The [documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) states

> In most cases the tool will refuse to operate unless a PRIMARY KEY or
>   UNIQUE INDEX is present in the table. See --alter for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't do that.
Running pt-online-schema-change on a table w/o a single column unique index, may result in a loss of data. See #3 here: http://www.pythian.com/blog/important-caveats-when-using-pt-online-schema-change/

Comment: Thanks! I posted a follow-up question regarding a workaround for this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30798499/260805